# Do I need to registger Android TV in order to receive casting?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-tv

I have downloaded https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android 
app and try to test it. It compiles and runs fine, it also connects to my 
Android TV, but it does not cast for some reason - I see movie thumbnail on 
TV and neverending loading bar at the bottom. Do I have to register app 
and\or device in Google Cast Developer Console (https://cast.google.com/publish/#/signup) in order for this to work?

I am using receiver app id provided in sample project above and
I have also tried using
.setReceiverApplicationId(CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID) 
instead, but had the same result all the time (receiver app connects, shows movie thumbnail, but does not cast).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
Per Ali Naddaf's comment - you should be able to use the non-default App Id without needing to register.

If you need to create an App Id, you'll need to register the device.

From: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers#Get_started

**Step 1 c.**

```
Register your Google Cast device at the Google Cast SDK Developer Console.
You must register the device so that you can use it for testing.
See Devices for more information about registering devices.
```

Comment: The above answer is incorrect; you only need to register a device if you are using a non-default App Id.